# Trouble on using the i18n gem with partial template files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to know how to correctly handle internationalization related to partial template files. That is, ...

... in my `app/views/users/flag.html.erb` file I have:

```
<%= t('.test_key1') %>
<%= render :partial => "/users/flag_form" %>
```

... in my `app/views/users/_flag_form.html.erb` file I have:

```
<%= t('.test_key2') %>
```

If in my `config/locales/views/users/en.yml` file (*note*: I am organizing files as stated in the [official RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files)) I use

```
en:
  users:
    flag:
      test_key1: Test 1 text
      test_key2: Test 2 text
```

*the `Test 1 text` is displayed in the "main" template* (`app/views/users/flag.html.erb`) *but the `Test 2 text` isn't for the partial template* (`app/views/users/_flag_form.html.erb`). **How could\should I solve this issue so to properly display the `Test 2 text`?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way would be to using scope, instead of "lazy loading" using the full stop.
Something like this should work:

```
I18n.t :test_key2, :scope => 'users.flag'
```

or use:

```
I18n.t "users.flag.test_key2"
```

Lastly, you could even pass it to the partial as in

```
<%= render :partial => "/users/flag_form", :locals => { :test_key => t('.test_key1') } %>
```

You should also checkout the appendix section on this website as it might be listing something that I am missing:
[https://web.archive.org/web/20120619002316/http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/where_is_Rails_trying_to_lookup_L10N_strings.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120619002316/http://www.unixgods.org/%7Etilo/Rails/where_is_Rails_trying_to_lookup_L10N_strings.html)

Answer (score 21):

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  users:
    flag:
      test_key1: Test 1 text
    flag_form:
      test_key2: Test 2 text
```

**app/views/users/flag.html.erb**

```
<%= t('.test_key1') %>
<%= render :partial => "/users/flag_form" %>
```

**app/views/users/_flag_form.html.erb**

```
<%= t('.test_key2') %>
```

**NB:**

1. Rails path to the view must match YAML path to the symbol. You need to create an entry at YAML file that matches the name of the view. Omit the trailing underscore since it's a partial.
2. Read more about [lazy lookups](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations)

Comment: TL;DR Keep the underscore in your _partial file name, build your YAML tree without the underscore. en: user: partial:

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this. What do you think about it?

```
def translate_for_partials key, *args
  I18n.t("#{params[:controller].gsub('/', '.')}.#{params[:action]}.#{key}", *args)
end
```

Is that bad to make such a method ?

Comment: In views you could do a cleaner version: 
I18n.t("#{controller_name}.#{controller.action_name}.#{key}")

Comment: Magnuss, this is for nested controllers `params[:controller].gsub('/', '.')`