# Rails 5: i18n for enum of namespaced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I'm a bit stuck with i18n for enum in namespaced model. At the moment I have line in model */app/media/medias.rb* like this:

```
enum territory: { local: 1, global: 2 }
```

in modal window  */views/media/medias/_newmedia.html.erb* I have this:

```
<%= f.select :territory, Media::Medias.territories.keys.collect 
{ |g| [(t'.territories.#{g.downcase}'), g] }, {}, {class:"form-control m-b"} %>
```

and in /config/locales/models/medias.en.yml I have this:

```
en:
  media:
    medias:
      territories:
        local: Local_EN
        global: Global_EN
```

**In console I see query is done, no error is thrown, but my view does not appear.** When I change to simple `Media::Medias.territories.keys` I get drop-down in view with key values in my view. **How do I fix this, please? Thank you!**

So far I've tried to implement [code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24783963/6873497). In view it gives translation nicely, however on create action I received error as it tried to save not enum key, but localized value.

**The solution**

Ok, it appears [this answer is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710247/6873497) in my case. If anyone needs here is how it should be done with namespaced model on my example:

1) in *model /app/media/medias.rb*

```
enum territory: { local: 1, global: 2 }

def self.territory_attributes_for_select
  territories.map do |territory, _|
    [I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{model_name.i18n_key}.territories.#{territory}"), territory]
  end
end
```

2) then in view partial */views/media/medias/_newmedia.html.erb*

```
<%= f.select :territory, options_for_select(Media::Medias.territory_attributes_for_select), 
{}, {class:"form-control m-b"} %>
```

3) and finaly in */config/locales/en.yml*

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      media/medias: #Important! This is how you define namespaced model!
        territories:
          local: "Local EN"
          global: "Global EN"
```

I can confirm correct locale is shown in view and then values are saved in create action.

Comment: `'.territories.#{g.downcase}'` should use double quotation.

Comment: @wesley6j Ok, I changed and now I can see view where there is enum value with first capital letter in dropdown, e.g., `Local` I still can't get my translation in view.

Comment: That is I18n problem with partial, check out this: [Trouble on using the i18n gem with partial template files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767706/trouble-on-using-the-i18n-gem-with-partial-template-files)

Comment: @wesley6j Do you think so? I can have static text localized in same partial. Problem I have is with enum particularly. I tried to use one piece of code which I link to in my question, but it does not work when saving form.

Comment: `f.select :territory, collection: Media::Medias.territories...`

Comment: @wesley6j I added solution which worked for me.